# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException when referenced Object is In DB

Tags: java, hibernate

I hava two entities A and B like this:

```
class A{
     ....
     B b;
}

class B{
     ....
}
```

**and there is an instance of B in Database with id 1.** now when I want to add an instance of A which has a reference to the B with id=1 I get this Exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging:
```

actually i get that exception  when i execute this code:

```
 entityManager.merge(a);
```

now if i change that to this:

```
a.setB(entityManager.find(B.class,a.getB().getId()))   // ensuring the object exist in DB
entityManager.merge(a);
```

then it works correctly! but I don't want to do that as the current B with id=1 may be different from the database version(and I want to save that in future and i don't want to save it now so i cant use cascade technique).

I know this question have been asked for thousands of times but all the answers say that the object B with id=1 should be in DB. OK it is there now but it's not working either. the only remaining point that may help is that b is an loaded by unmarshallinga a json string so its not loaded by Hibernate.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you loaded object 'a' before this line of code entityManager.merge(a); ?

Answer (score 0):

If its a new instance it means its a transient instance and has no relation with the DB hence it can't save it. Only way is you have to load 'a' and then set as in your second set of code.

Comment: The difference is in the first piece of code when you merge 'a' it also expects valid value for 'b' associated with 'a' due to the defined relation mapping.  But as you are not setting this value 'b' to 'a' you get this error. But in second case you are setting some valid 'b' object before you save 'a', hence it works without error.